# Which is the software package for creation of PDF documents on Debian and OpenBSD OSes?

Tags: debian, pdf, openbsd

I have installed the software package called `evince`. It only opens and reads PDF files but does not create them.

What software package should I install on boxes that run Debian (or OpenBSD) that can create PDF documents?

I do not wish to install OpenOffice or LibreOffice.

Comment: Please elaborate on why you don't want to run Open- or LibreOffice. It will make it easier for people to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install `cups-pdf` which gives you the ability to print to PDF from any package.

The output files normally show up in `~/PDF` (as the printer driver has no way to ask you where to store the file it creates)

E.g. in Firefox do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then select the PDF printer:

[image]

---

<sub>Sorry for the missing [Droste effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect)</sub>

Comment: Is `cups-pdf` able to print web pages in a browser session?

Comment: @user66229 Sure, as long as you tell your browser that you want to use the PDF as the "printer" destination.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want to do. There are many programs that can produce PDF files. You can install `cups-pdf` as suggested by @Anthon to be able to print to PDF from any program, and you can also use one or more of:

- LaTeX : a professional typesetting language that can produce PDFs via `pdflatex`.
- `ps2pdf` : converts postscript documents to PDFs. You can combine it with things like `e2ps` which converts text to postscript: `e2ps foo | ps2pdf - foo.pdf` or `enscript -p - foo | ps2pdf - foo.pdf`.
- `webkit2pdf` : export web pages to PDF files or printer
- `html2ps` : `html2ps foo.html | ps2pdf - foo.pdf`
- `txt2html` : `txt2html foo | html2ps | ps2pdf - foo.pdf`

Comment: I read up about LaTeX on Wikipedia and it seems that LaTeX is not a computer program. If I wish to install it on Debian, what package would it be? On OpenBSD, what package would that be?

Comment: On `packages.debian.org`, there's no such package called `ps2pdf`.

Comment: @user66229 on debian it would be `texlive-latex-base` and you will probably also need `pdflatex`. LaTeX is a language, not a program, true. As for `ps2pdf`, it is part of the `ghostscript` package on Debian. No idea for the BSDs.

Comment: I searched on `packages.debian.org` and there's no such package named `pdflatex`.

Comment: @user66229 yes, it's actually part of `texlive-latex-base`. When you search on packages.debian.org, also search for ["packages that contain files named like this"](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pdflatex&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any).